# Type casting needed for byte = byte - byte?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

I have the following code:

```
foreach (byte b in bytes)
{
    byte inv = byte.MaxValue - b;
    // Add the new value to a list....
}
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Each part of this statement is a byte.  Why does C# want to convert the `byte.MaxValue - b` to an int?

Shouldn't you be able to do this some how without casting? (i.e. I don't want to have to do this: `byte inv = (byte) (byte.MaxValue - b);`)

Answer (score 4):

According to the [C# Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> because the arithmetic expression on the right-hand side of the assignment operator evaluates to int by default.

The reason for this could be because your processor is going to be faster at accessing a 4-byte memory address than a 1-byte memory address, so arithmetic operators are defined to work on 4-byte operands.

Comment: I guess the question is why?  When I do `int-int` it does not result in an `int64`.  Why auto-promote the type when it is `byte-byte`?

Comment: @Vaccano: My guess is so that arithmetic operators only have to be defined to work with certain length operands (4-byte and 8-byte), but I'm only speculating.

Comment: even if MSIL only supports module-2**32 arithmetic, the C# compiler would still be free to insert a narrowing conversion when necessitated by storage of the result into a variable as narrow as the operands.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I instinctively never want the compiler to insert a narrowing cast for me.  However, I suppose in this case you are implicitly telling it to do the cast by assigning the result to a byte.  I can't find any fault in your logic.

Comment: I only want the compiler to insert casts when they conform to the type system.  Since in my opinion saving the result of byte & byte into another byte is type safe, the compiler can do that with whatever sequence of instructions is most efficient.  If that happens to be a 32-bit wide AND followed by a narrowing cast, it hasn't broken type safety so it's perfectly ok IMO.

Answer (score 2):

For addition, multiplication, and subtraction, there's a fairly good explanation: Including the carry bits in the calculation and then throwing them away is far easier than figuring out the carry bits if they were thrown away originally.

For bitwise operators (intersection, inclusive union, exclusive union, complement) that reasoning simply doesn't hold water.  The only thing I can think of is that sign-extension would be somewhat ambiguous if you started with a mixture of signed and unsigned operands and then saved the result in a wider type.  But that doesn't explain why bitwise operations which are unary or where all operands have the same type should widen the result to `int`.  I consider it a very annoying design flaw with C# that:

```
byte a, b;
byte c = a | b;
```

generates an error.

Comment: I agree with your overall point, but isn't this an "annoying design flaw" in C# rather than .NET?  F# defines logical and arithmetic operations on bytes which return bytes, for instance.